# NSLog suppress date

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I find NSLog() statements really hard to read because of the verbose date.

Is there a way to suppress the date on NSLog?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/different-nslog  That's a page on our CocoaHeads wiki explaining how to create your own `NSLog()` alternative (that does useful things, like print file name and line number).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you'll have to write your own log method if you want it in a different format.